# I had been practicing or I practiced

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions, time-reference

I've always used 'had been' in conditionals but today I was talking with a friend online and before logging in I practiced speaking English with myself for 30 minutes. So I said:
"I had been practicing for 30 minutes before coming here."

1) Was my sentence correct given the context?

2) Could I have also said:
"I practiced for 30 minutes before coming here."

Answer (score 2):

The auxiliary verb *had* is used in English to mark what we might call “the past of the past.” Consider the sentence,

> I had just fallen asleep when the phone rang.

As we interpret it, we conclude that the phone’s ringing has by now passed **and** that by the now-past moment of its ringing, the speaker’s falling asleep was **already** in the past.

So if your own first sentence ended, “...when I came here,” then “had been practicing” would be the best wording. But as you worded it, it sounds a bit off. Your second sentence is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Do you mean "I had been practicing.....when I came here? Here's another one, please let me know if this one's correct- I just had a burger and said, "That was really good cause I had been craving a burger for the past few days."

Comment: Yes to both questions.